# Spark 1.6 a dataframe insert to Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

i am trying to insert to cassandra a dataframe.

When i write 
rdd.tosaveToCasssandra("keyspace","table")

Not problem but i can't write with this function

```
myDataFrame.tosaveToCassandra("keyspace","table")
```

Also i tried but didn't save.

```
myDataFrame.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").mode('append').options(table="mytable", keyspace="mykeyspace").save()
```

Do you have any idea except from new API for Spark 2.0

Thanks

Comment: The first attempt is incorrect. That is for RDDS only,

The second approach is correct. Why do you think it didn't save?

Comment: I dont think you gave the options properly. It expects a map, you can rather try this way paddedGtpProfiles.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").mode(SaveMode.Append).option("table","mytable").option("keyspace","mykeyspace").save()

Comment: Did you get any error.?

Answer (score 0):

For python there is currently no streaming Sink for Cassandra in the Spark Cassandra Connector, you will have to implement your own.